# Git open specific file on certain commit without changing working tree

Tags: git

Is there a way to do the following:

I'm working on a dirty working tree. There's a commit (maybe in another branch) that I'd like to reference while coding something. Is there a way to check out a specific file in that commit (open it from within my text editor) without changing the state of the working tree?

Essentially, this would be equivalent to stashing, checking out, and going back. However, what I want (ideally) is for there to be NO state changes to the working tree; git uses the editor of choice (for me, `emacsclient`) and opens a temporary buffer (like the commit message) displaying the contents of this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out there's an emacs-specific solution.

Using VC, Emacs's interface to version control systems, you can use the sequence <kbd>C-x v ~</kbd> which runs the command `vc-revision-other-window`. It does exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things you can do.

The easiest is probably to use the `git worktree` command to check out the commit you want in another directory.  E.g., if you're working in a directory `myproject` and you realize you need to see a file as it existed in commit `1234567`, you can run:

```
git worktree add ../oldversion 1234567
```

This will create the directory `../oldversion`, which will contain your repository as it existed at commit `1234567`.  When you're done with that tree:

```
rm -rf ../oldversion
git worktree prune
```

---

You can also get what you want using the `git cat-file` command:

```
git cat-file -p 1234567:path/to/file
```

Or:

```
git show 1234567:path/to/file
```

This will output the file on *stdout*.

Comment: My favorite method for this particular kind of case: `git show <hash>:path` produces its contents to stdout (though in old Git versions, this suppresses end-of-line munging and other `.gitattributes` work, so beware of that). There's probably some Emacs functions (probably *many* actually) that will do this directly into a buffer.

Comment: In anything not too ancient, you can also just `git cat-file -p <commit>:<path>`: `git cat-file` uses the rev-parse code, and rev-parse can translate directly from commit-and-path to tree or blob object.

Comment: Updated based on comments!